# How to insert date value into vertica

Tags: python, vertica

I am writing small application in python which read records from Oracle and insert them into Vertica.

To read from Oracle I am using the `cx_Oracle` python package and to write into Vertica I am using the `pyodbc` package.

When I read a date column from Oracle I get it in the following format:

```
datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 13, 10, 47, 54, 795658)
```

Edit:

When I hit the following query in vertica :

```
INSERT INTO "TEST" (COL1) values(datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 13, 10, 47, 54, 795658))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: ERROR: schema "datetime" does not exist
SQLState:  3F000
ErrorCode: 0
```

My question is how to convert this into a Vertica time stamp column.

Comment: This should work without any problems or manual conversion; `pyodbc` can handle `datetime.datetime` instances natively (they are translated to SQL_TIMESTAMP values). If this doesn't work, it would be a problem with the ODBC driver, not python.

Comment: I am running the following query in Vertica and in return an error:
INSERT INTO "TEST" (COL1) values(datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 13, 10, 47, 54, 795658))

Comment: You need to tell us *what* error. Full traceback please, you can add it to your question. See [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186) for help on formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to mix Python code and SQL; your Vertica server is trying to interpret the `datetime.datetime` information as a SQL schema, and it fails.

Use [parameters](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/GettingStarted#Parameters) instead:

```
from datetime import datetime

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO "TEST" (COL1) values(?)',
    datetime(2011, 9, 13, 10, 47, 54, 795658))
```

Comment: I mixed it in purpose to show that datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 13, 10, 47, 54, 795658) is fail on Vertica.
I tried to run your solution and I got the following exception:
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: Adjusted example; you imported the `datetime` type from the module, I assumed you imported just the module.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am saying; look at the datetime reference in the example.